# Regarding Licenses

Tags: licenses

May I know how many types of Licenses available in sales force? I need the licenses associated with the products. Can anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 4):

Inside Salesforce, you must assign User licenses on the user profile page. Each user is required to have a license associated to it.

[image]

The list of those [licenses can be found here](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_available.htm&language=en_US).

---

Those licenses relate to the licenses Salesforce actually sells. The specific licenses available for an org can be viewed on the [Company Information page](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_profile.htm&language=en_US).

[image]

You can find more detail on those [license types here](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_understanding_license_types.htm&language=en_US).

---

There is also the concept of Feature Licenses. These licenses can be applied on a per user basis found on the user profile as checkboxes.

[image]

The available feature licenses an org has can also be viewed on the Company Information page.

[image]

The full list of [feature licenses can be found here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_feature_licenses_available.htm&language=en_US).

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below details which I am attaching will help everyone to have pretty good information on Licenses !

License
In Salesforce, every user is identified by a username, password, and a single profile. The profile determines what tasks users can perform, what data they see, and what they can do with the data
A user license entitles a user to different functionality within Salesforce and determines which profiles and permission sets are available to the user.
License Types :
•   Salesforce
•   Communities
•   Customer Portal
•   Customer Portal — Enterprise Administration
•   Database.com User Licenses
•   Partner Portal
•   Platform Portal
•   Service Cloud Portal
•   Sites and Site.com

•   Salesforce  : Designed for users who require full access to standard CRM and Force.com AppExchange apps. Users with this user license are entitled to access any standard or custom app.
   Salesforce Platform :  Designed for users who need access to custom apps but not to standard CRM functionality.

   Force.com – One App : Force.com - One App users are entitled to the same rights as Salesforce Platform users, plus they have access to an unlimited number of custom tabs.

   Force.com AppSubscription : A Force.com Light App has up to 10 custom objects and 10 custom tabs, has read-only access to accounts and contacts, and supports object-level and field-level security. A Force.com Light App can’t use the Bulk API or Streaming API.

   Knowledge Only User : Designed for users who only need access to the Salesforce Knowledge app.

   Identity : Grants users access to Identity features such as the App Launcher. To view and use the App Launcher, a user must have the “Use Identity Features” permission.

   Chatter Free :  These users can access standard Chatter people, profiles, groups, and files

   Chatter External : Designed to allow customers in Chatter groups. Customers are users outside of a company’s email domain

   Chatter Plus : These users can access standard Chatter people, profiles, groups, and files, plus they can: View Salesforce accounts and contacts
Use Salesforce CRM Content, Ideas, and Answers
Modify up to ten custom objects

   Work.com Only User : Designed for users who don’t have a Salesforce license and need access to Work.com.

   Company Community : This is an internal user license. It’s designed for users to access Force.com Light application custom objects, custom tabs, Chatter (people, groups, feeds, files), and aCommunity that includes a Site.com site.

•   Communities :

   Customer Community : The Customer Community license is similar to a High Volume Customer Portal license and is well-suited for business-to-consumer communities with large numbers of external users
   Partner Community : The Partner Community license is similar to a Gold Partner license and is well-suited for business-to-business communities, such as a partner community.

•     Customer Portal : It allows contacts to log into your Customer Portal to manage customer  support.

•     Customer Portal — Enterprise Administration User Licenses :  The Overage Customer Portal Manager Custom license is the same as the Customer Portal Manager Custom license, except that users do not have unlimited logins.

•     Database.com User Licenses :
   Database.com Admin : Designed for users who need to administer Database.com, or make changes to Database.com schemas or other metadata using the point-and-click tools in the Database.com Console. 
   Database.com User : Designed for users who need API access to data stored in Database.com. 
   Database.com Light User : Designed for users who need only API access to data, need to belong to Chatter groups (but no other groups), and don't need to belong to roles or queues.

•     Partner Portal User Licenses : Partner Portal users have the Gold Partner user license. They can only access Salesforce using the partner portal.

•     Platform Portal User Licenses : Platform portal users have the Authenticated Website license, which is designed to be used with Force.com Sites. It gives named sites users unlimited logins to your Platform Portal to access customer support information.

•     Service Cloud Portal User Licenses : This license gives contacts unlimited logins to your Service Cloud Portal to access customer support information. Users with this license can access accounts, assets, cases, contacts, custom objects, documents, ideas, and questions, depending on their permission settings.

•     Sites and Site.com Licenses :

   Guest User : Designed for public users who access your Site.com or Force.com sites. For each Guest User license, you can develop one site for your organization.

   Site.com Only : Site.com Only users are entitled to the same rights as Force.com - One App users, plus they have access to the Content app. Each Site.com Only user also needs either a Site.com Contributor or Site.com Publisher feature license to access Site.com.

Feature Licenses :  A feature license entitles a user to an additional Salesforce feature, such as Marketing or Connect Offline.

Available feature licenses : Chatter Answers User, Force.com Flow User, Knowledge User, Live Agent User, Marketing User, Mobile User, Offline User, Salesforce CRM Content User, Service Cloud User, Site.com Contributor User, Site.com Publisher User, Work.com User

```
Editions
```

Products    Contact Manager Group   Professional    Corporate   Enterprise  Performance
Sales   Yes Yes Yes -   Yes Yes
Service -   -   Yes -   Yes Yes
Marketing   -   Yes Yes Yes Yes -
Platform ( force.com )  -   -   -   -   Yes Yes
Chatter -   -   Yes -   Yes -
Work.com    -   -   Yes -   Yes -